# NgIf checking value json object is not working

Tags: angular, ionic4

l have IONIC app using angular . My app getting data json api for flights schedule . everything is working fine , but l have problem withe some values are coming nulls or empty and when those values comes null or empty l get on empty data in html   and most of datas are not shows  .

[image: When l get null string or empty]

error code is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of null`

Here is code has that error

```
<td *ngFor="let item of items">

                <div *ngIf="item.flight.airline.code.icao">
                  {{item?.flight.airline.code.icao}}
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="!item.flight.airline.code.icao=null">
                  N/A
                </div>
              </td>
```

And l still have same error ! . any solution please ?

Comment: The error says "Cannot read property 'code' of null". The code has `*ngIf="item.flight.airline.code.icao"`. Conclusion: `item.flight.airline` is null, and you're trying to read its code propery, hence the error.

Comment: Also note that `=` is the assignment operator, not a comparison operator.

Comment: But l have objects inside  `airline` and `airline` never comes null , null is coming only with `code`

Comment: Then either you're wrong, or something other than the code you posted is throwing that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is `item.flight.airline` is null so you can't access the property `code` from it

changing the code to the following should fix your problem:

```
<td *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div *ngIf="item.flight.airline && item.flight.airline.code.icao">
     {{item?.flight.airline.code.icao}}
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="!item.flight.airline || !item.flight.airline.code.icao">
     N/A
   </div>
</td>
```